# Agregar 2 inputs uno al lado del otro en la misma columna

Tags: css, bootstrap-3

Estoy armando un formulario en Bootstrap, y quiero que en la misma fila y la misma columna haya 2 inputs, uno al lado del otro.

Probé con la clase `input-group`, con la que pude agregar botones y etiquetas a los inputs, pero cuando meto 2 inputs dentro de un `input-group` el segundo input pasa abajo del primero, y yo quiero que quede al lado del primero y pegado, como pasa con los `input-group-addon`.

¿Cómo se podrá lograr eso? En lo posible usando las clases propias de Bootstrap.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Nro. remito</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input name="remitosucursal" id="remitosucursal" type="text" required class="form-control">
      <input name="remitonumero" id="remitonumero" type="text" required class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Una opción sería añadir un `input-group-addon` entre los campos y dejar que Bootstrap se encargue de los estilos.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Nro. remito</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input name="remitosucursal" id="remitosucursal" type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="Sucursal">
          <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
          <input name="remitonumero" id="remitonumero" type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="Numero">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Otra opción si no quieres añadir `input-group-addon`, sería crear estilos propios (aunque no sé si eso es lo que quieres por lo que dices en la pregunta). Aquí dejo un ejemplo:

```css
.two-fields {
  width:100%;
}
.two-fields .input-group {
  width:100%;
}
.two-fields input {
  width:50% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group two-fields">
        <label for="">Nro. remito</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input name="remitosucursal" id="remitosucursal" type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="Sucursal">
          <input name="remitonumero" id="remitonumero" type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="Numero">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probé todas las alternativas y me quedo con esta. Al final usé los estilos personalizados, aunque es buena idea lo del `input-group-addon` con el guión, no se me había ocurrido

Answer (score 3):

En lo personal se me hace mas facil el acomodo pensando los espacios de columna a doce,
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Nombre:
>                       
>                       
>                           
>                       
>                   
>                   
>                       
>                           Apellido:
>
> ```
>                 <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-top:2px;">
>
>                     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
>                         <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
>                             <label for="email">Email:</label>
>                         </div>
>                         <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 ">
>                             <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" tabindex="4">
>                         </div>
>                     </div>
>                     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
>                         <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 ">
>                             <label for="celular">Celular:</label>
>                         </div>
>                         <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 ">
>                             <input type="number" name="celular" id="celular" class="form-control" placeholder="Celular" tabindex="3">
>                         </div>
>                     </div>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Si los textbox estan uno al lado del otro seran ubicados en la misma fila, pero no en la misma columna

```html
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" /> 
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" /> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Observaras que ubico cada `input` en un `div` diferente indicando un `col-*-6`, defino un 6 para especificas las 12 columnas del `grid system` de `bootstrap`

En el ejemplo anterior plantee la solucion que me parecía mejor se adaptaba

[Input group - two inputs close to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954117/input-group-two-inputs-close-to-each-other)

Pero es cierto que con el `input-group-addon` se podria ubicar texto al costado del control, pero esto lo he visto mas que nada para poner algun texto (por eso se aplica en un `span`), no para alinear otro control

Comment: Pero, si no me equivoco, lo que está pidiendo es que estén en la misma columna, es decir, dentro del primer `col-xs-6` según tu ejemplo

Comment: Sencillo, pones en el mismo div dos div internos y ya está.

Answer (score 2):

Una opción es utilizar [Inline forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline).

Modifiqué el ejemplo que incluiste en tu pregunta para usar `Inline forms` (en la vista previa vas a ver que aparece en una sola columna, porque es el default de `Extra Small`, pero se puede ajustar si quieres que aún en ese tamaño los campos queden dispuestos horizontalmente):

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Nro. remito</label>
      <input name="remitosucursal" id="remitosucursal" type="text" required class="form-control">
    </div>
    <input name="remitonumero" id="remitonumero" type="text" required class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Te dejo esta alternativa, ojala te sirva:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <label for="">Nro. remito</label>
  <div class="row col-xs-12">
      <input name="remitosucursal" id="remitosucursal" type="text" required  placeholder="Sucursal" class="col-xs-6">
      <input name="remitonumero" id="remitonumero" type="text" required placeholder="Numero"  class="col-xs-6">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Lo validé y si me funcionó.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que también te puede ayudar y es mas corto es:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 input-group input-group-sm">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Nro. remito</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
  <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```

para poder poner dos inputs en la misma linea